# Cannot update excel file using VBScript on SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript

I have the following simple VBScript for updating an Excel workbook.

```
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Visible = False

objExcel.Workbooks.Open "path\myworkbook.xlsx"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit

Set objExcel = Nothing
```

When I use `path` to local excel file like `C:\Users\sbrbot\Documents\myworkbook.xlsx` the script works and updates my excel workbook fine. But when I use the remote path like `\\sharepoint\library\myworkbook.xlsx` then script executes without errors (so path is correct) but the workbook is not really updated! (SharePoint version 2013). Even if I map SharePoint's remote server path `\\sharepoint\library` to logical `M:\` drive, and my path is `M:\myworkbook.xlsx` the same is hapening, it does not update workbook. Seems like SharePoint refuses to update file. Path is correct, that's not the problem.

I have to mention one strange bahaviour with SharePoint. When I manually open Excel file from SharePoint remote directory, make some changes in it, and save the file - in Excel's titlebar it is reported as Saved. Immediately after this when I go to close this Excel file, Excel asks me to save it again although I did not change anything inside the file.

Comment: What is the new data expected, is it come with RefreshAll? If true, is it connect to an external source that might not work from remote, or it takes too long to get completed?

Comment: Excel workbook is connected to data cube and with RefreshAll method new data is fetched from Analysis server into workbook and it should be saved. In my real script at the end of script I have message box announcing that job is finished when script completes (in reality it takes cca 80 seconds). So it's not that!